# Change Default Save as EPS options

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, eps

I need a little bit of help regarding "save as .eps" file -

I want the Custom transparency vector balance to be 0 always, when saving as .eps.

kindly find image below, I am Using Illustrator CS6

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Care to share why you'd want to push raster as much as possible in an EPS? Usually it's the other way around - push vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **"Edit>Transparency Flattener Presets"** and create a new Preset and save settings and it will appear on save dialog box as well as PDF's Advance option.

Comment: i have did that but i have to select preset manually each time its not automatically loading